# Why I can't rotate the Player transform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Player is a child of a parent object and the Player have his own child a camera.
The Player start when the Z on Rotation is to 50 and X and Y are 0.

[image: Player]

Then I'm using the Player Animator controller with animation to change the Z only from 50 to 0.
When the game start the Player is changing from 50 to 0 on the Z.

The Player have some components attached to it I tried to remove each one by one while the game is running but nothing changed/helped.

The Player have attached a Rigidbody and a Controller script.

The Player Camera have attached to it a Player Camera Controller script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    private UnityEngine.GameObject player;
    private Vector2 mouseLook;
    private Vector2 smoothV;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        player = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (PauseManager.gamePaused == false)
        {
            var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

            md = Vector2.Scale(md, new Vector2(sensitivity * smoothing, sensitivity * smoothing));
            smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
            smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);
            mouseLook += smoothV;

            mouseLook.y = Mathf.Clamp(mouseLook.y, -90f, 90f);

            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseLook.y, Vector3.right);
            player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseLook.x, Vector3.up);
        }
    }
}
```

I can use the mouse to rotate the camera around 360 degrees.
And it's changing the Player rotation on the Y only when using the mouse.

But then I tried while the game is running to set a new values to the Player rotation on the X Y and Z but nothing changed.

For some reason it's changing the rotation and I see the Player rotating with the Animator or with the mouse but when I change the Player rotation values nothing happens.

I also tried to attach a simple script for testing but nothing changed when pressing on L button :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            var player = GameObject.Find("Player");
            player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, 25);
        }
    }
}
```

I can'r figure out how to rotate the Player and why I can't rotate it on my own but I can with the mouse controller script or the animator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PlayerCameraController` script is overwriting the rotation based on the field `mouseLook`. It doesn't take the current rotation of the player or the camera into account at all, and so it just overwrites any changes.

Instead of using a `mouseLook` field, modify the camera's `localEulerAngles` and use `Rotate` on the player's `transform`.

```
public class PlayerCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float smoothing = 2.0f;

    private UnityEngine.GameObject player;
    private Vector2 smoothV;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        player = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (PauseManager.gamePaused == false)
        {
            var md = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

            md = sensitivity * smoothing * md;
            smoothV.x = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.x, md.x, 1f / smoothing);
            smoothV.y = Mathf.Lerp(smoothV.y, md.y, 1f / smoothing);

            Vector3 modifiedEulers = transform.localEulerAngles + Vector3.left * smoothV.y; 

            // transform euler angles from [0,360) to [-180,180) before clamp
            modifiedEulers.x = Mathf.Repeat(modifiedEulers.x + 180f, 360f) - 180f;
            modifiedEulers.x = Mathf.Clamp(modifiedEulers.x, -90f, 90f);

            transform.localEulerAngles = modifiedEulers;
            player.transform.Rotate(0f, smoothV.x, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```